# Update Label.text setNeedsDisplay() not working - Swift

Tags: swift, setneedsdisplay

I have a complex table of calculations that loops for every day of the year. At the end of each day's loop I want to update the screen. These are all myLabel.text output. view.setNeedsDisplay() ain't working. Do I need to call it externally or use something else? E.g.

```
for var day = 1; day < 366; day++ {
     dayLabel.text = String(format: "%i", day)
     view.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

Comment: You should not need the setNeedsDisplay there - changing the label text should be sufficient to trigger the view to change. That is an add looking for loop for Swift - unless you know better try 'for day in 1...365 {'

Comment: This func is called when a button is pressed (IBAction). Basically you have to force the display update, otherwise it will only update when the loop has completed. view.setNeedsDisplay and testLabel.setNeedsDisplay() don't do it. In Cocoa the approach was tortuous like:  [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateDisplayEnergySunEquator:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:distanceFromSun] waitUntilDone:YES];

Comment: OK. Can you confirm that the Objective C style of 'for loop' works in Swift? It does actually loop round 365 times?

Comment: If I put in an NSLog() line then the NSLog prints in real-time. The UILabel however only updates when the loop has finished.

Comment: OK, so that was all a Red Herring - sorry about that. So perhaps either a threading issue or just a speed issue as outline [in this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3459308/2466193)?

Comment: That's how you used to do in Cocoa (see my first comment). I suspect the answer is to use dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0) but I can't work out how to position it in the code. To date it's behaving like the original code posted.

Comment: Ah, OK. I have an example of dispatch_async in Swift in my code - I'll post it in an answer for formatting reasons...

Comment: @EdwardHasted The fact that this loop is on a background thread is crucial to determining the answer to your problem.  As such, you should absolutely update your *question* to include this information.  Posting it in the comments does not suffice.

Comment: I appreciate and know that. The view is not updated until the loop finished.
This is the essence of the question. In Swift how do you update the screen in a background thread. Ali's example below doesn't work. With many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From the comment discussion above we think it just needs the label change to be forced onto the main thread. In swift:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
     dayLabel.text = String(format: "%i", day)
}
```

Or using a bit more Swift notation:

```
for day in 1...365 {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        dayLabel.text = "\(day)"
    }
}
```

Comment: Same thing, only updates when the loop has finished. Here's the code I was using:    @IBAction func calculatePower(sender: AnyObject) {

        for day in 1...365 {


            // Update Display at end of Loop

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

                self.dayLabel.text = "\(day)"

            }

        }

    }

Comment: Sorry, don't know how to preserve the layout state when posting a comment in StackOverflow. All goes onto a contiguous line.

Comment: @EdwardHasted All I can think of now is that a 0 to 365 loop will happen awful quick and perhaps all those changes are just pilling up and only the last one is being seen. Break points may be misleading as that will stop the main thread and thus stop the updates.

Comment: Indeed it does. I typically change the number to 36500 when running tests to check for exactly that reason ;-)

Comment: Ali - I'm going to repost this question in a different guise with some more code and then delete this one as it didn't reach a conclusion. Very many thanks for your help and patience.